# WideImage only working for some Images

Tags: php, thumbnails, gd, wideimage

WideImage is only working for some images. I can't figure out why, because the images are same filetype and same dimensions.

Here is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'WideImage/WideImage.php';

function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {
    try {
        WideImage::loadFromFile($src)->resize($desired_width, 50)->saveToFile($dest);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'EXCEPTION: '.$e;
    }   
}
?>
```

**Function call**

```
echo 'Thumb Creation Started';
make_thumb($filename, $thumbname, 100);
echo 'Thumb Creation Finished';
```

I'm receiving the following errror:

EDIT: This error is only occuring when i resend the data with firebug. At first there is no error shown.

> Thumb Creation StartedEXCEPTION: exception
>   'WideImage_InvalidImageSourceException' with message 'File 
>   '/kunden/homepages/33/d582216481/htdocs/uploads/downloads/image
>   .png' appears to be an invalid image source.' in
>   /homepages/33/d582216481/htdocs/includes
>   /WideImage/WideImage.php:226 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /homepages/33/d582216481/htdocs/includes/phpThumb.php(12):
>
> WideImage::loadFromFile(' /kunden/homepag...')
>
> ## 1 /homepages/33/d582216481/htdocs/includes/addDownload.php(60):
>
> make_thumb('/kunden/homepag ...', '/kunden/homepag...', 100)
>
> ## 2 {main}Thumb Creation Started

Can somebody explain, why it is working for some images, and for some not??

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Basic Conf
require_once ('basic_config.php');
// PHP Thumb
require_once ('phpThumb.php');
// DB INIT
require_once ($full_url.'includes/db.php');

// GET DATA FROM POST
$pid = $_POST['downloadProdukt'];
$downloadBezeichnung = $_POST['downloadBezeichnung'];
$downloadDatei = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['downloadDatei']['name']);
$downloadKategorie = $_POST['downloadKategorie'];
$downloadSize = $_FILES['downloadDatei']['size'];

// GET Image adjustments
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["downloadDatei"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];

// GET FOLDER OF THE PRODUCT
$cols = Array ("PID","OrdnerName");
$db->where ('PID', $pid);
$produkte = $db->get ("produkt", null, $cols);
if ($db->count > 0){
    foreach ($produkte as $produkt) {
        $uploadFolder = $produkt['OrdnerName'];
    }
}

// FILE
$filePath = $upload_url . $uploadFolder . "downloads/";
$rel_file_path = $uploadFolder . "downloads/";
$filename = $filePath .  $downloadDatei;
$thumbname = $filePath .  "thumb_" . $downloadDatei;

// Falls Ordner nicht existiert erstelle neu
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);
}

// Move file to Dir
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['downloadDatei']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
    //echo "Original Datei erfolgreich hochgeladen.\n";
} else {
    echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";
}

// IF Image --> Generate Thumb
if (
        // Wenn dateityp BILD
        $_FILES['downloadDatei']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' OR
        $_FILES['downloadDatei']['type'] == 'image/png' OR
        $_FILES['downloadDatei']['type'] == 'image/gif'
){
    echo 'Thumb Creation Started';
    make_thumb($filename, $thumbname, 100);
    $thumbname = "thumb_" . $downloadDatei;
    echo 'Thumb Creation Finished';
} else {
    $thumbname = null;
    echo 'Kein Thumb';
}

// EXECUTE QUERY
$data = Array ("PID" => $pid,
                'DownloadBez' => $downloadBezeichnung,
                'DownloadKat' => $downloadKategorie,
                'DownloadDatei' => $downloadDatei,
                'DownloadOrdner' => $rel_file_path,
                'DownloadSize' => $downloadSize,
                'DownloadThumb' => $thumbname
            );
$id = $db->insert ('downloads', $data);
```

?>

[Not working](http://zte-partner.de/uploads/ZTE_Blade_V7/downloads/ZTE_Blade_V7_Rueckseiten_liegend_RGB.png)
[working](http://zte-partner.de/uploads/ZTE_Blade_V7/downloads/ZTE_Blade_V7_R%C3%BCckseite_schwebend_RGB.png)

Comment: Does it has to do something with the type of the file? Were all the images png or jpg?

Comment: both png and same dimensions

Comment: Can you check if the source is given properly, I see a space between image  and .png. Is it true?

Comment: no space or any kind of special character

Comment: i think the space was caused by copy pasting out of firebug, as the filetype was in a new line

Comment: Okay, can you add both images you are trying to load?

Comment: added them to the description

Comment: This isn't showing up; is it corrupted? http://zte-partner.de/uploads/ZTE_Blade_V7/downloads/ZTE_Blade_V7_Rueckseiten_liegend_RGB.png

Comment: maybe interesting to know:
The error is only occuring when i resend the form via firebug. When i upload the file normally there is no error occuring. but there is still no thumb generated and the php script seems to be stopping as "Thumb Creation Finished" is not echoed